# transferutility transfer failed s3

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3, download, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to download files from an s3 bucket, yet I keep on getting an illegalstateexception with the message "Transfer failed."
Upload works fine. Here is my code and a stacktrace. Anyone know what might be wrong? (Last note, image.url is not an entire url, its an objectKey)

```
File parent = new File(getFilesDir() + "/images");
parent.mkdirs();
File file = new File(getFilesDir() + "/images/" + image.url);
File thumbFile = new File(getFilesDir() + "/images/" + image.thumbUrl);

System.out.println("File path: " + file.getPath());
System.out.println("Thumbnail path: " + thumbFile.getPath());

TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.download(
        BUCKET_NAME,     /* The bucket to download from */
        image.url,    /* The key for the object to download */
        file        /* The file to download the object to */
    );
observer.setTransferListener(downloadListener);
```

> Download with id 313 encountered an error: Transfer failed.
>    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transfer failed.
>       at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferObserver$TransferContentObserver.onChange(TransferObserver.java:219)
>       at android.database.ContentObserver.onChange(ContentObserver.java:129)
>       at android.database.ContentObserver$NotificationRunnable.run(ContentObserver.java:180)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. I thought it was enough to grant "everyone" read access to my bucket. In reality, I had to set a bucket policy to make every file that is uploaded get those setting as well. I used this policy:

{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}